# How to hold some assets till the a contract has been finished?

Tags: asch-development, asch

For instance i like to create some kind of betting contract between two users (addresses)
User1 pays 1 asset, then we wait for User2 who also pays 1 asset, now the contract choose a random winner who got both (2) assets.

The issue is not the possibility per se, but about the number of fees to pay.

What works

- User1 pays 1 asset to the bank (1 asset + 1 fee)
- User2 pays 1 asset to the bank (1 asset + 1 fee)
- The bank pays to the winner (2 asset +    1 fee, the bank has to pay fees too)

total number of fees used: 3

Question

- User1 pays 1 asset (1 asset + 1 fee) wait... until
- User2 pays 1 asset AND send 2 assets to the winner in the same contract (1 fee)

total number of fees used: 2

When the balance of user1 is checked at the start of the contract, he can start a new contract with the same balance when we wait for user2?